# Removing characters from the back of a variable in batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a variable that I want remove a set amount of characters from the back.
I could use this code to do this but the "username" could be 1 characters or 20.

`set var=%input:~1,10%`

but what I do know is how long the text after the "username"
I have a variable with the following string.

`"Username :   Knowntext"`

I want to remove all the text at the end of the variable so that all that is left is the username. 
If it deletes a set amount of characters, that will work.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to taking positive numbers, string manipulation in batch can also take negative numbers. When you do this, you start at the rightmost character and work your way to the left.

```
@echo off

set "input=Username :   Knowntext"

:: Get everything except the last 14 characters
set var=%input:~0,-14%
echo %var%
pause
```